# Initializing class instance similar to records in F#

Tags: .net, f#

With record types in F# you can use a syntax like this to initialize a record based on another one:

```
let rr3 = { defaultRecord1 with field2 = 42 }
```

Is there something similarly concise and elegant for non-record types as well?

I'm working with C# classes and calling their `Clone()` method and doing assignments to their properties using the `<-` operator seems a bit off. I also found this article about [object expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233237.aspx) but it seems it isn't the thing I was looking for.

Edit: So to sum it up I'm trying to instantiate C# classes in my F# code and I'm wondering if there is some concise syntax for creating an object of a class based on another object's values just like with records in F# using the `with` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use settable properties in method calls as if they were named arguments. So if your class was implemented with a dedicated `Clone` method that returns the original type:

```
type Foo() =
    member val X = 0 with get, set
    member val Y = 0 with get, set
    member this.Clone() = new Foo(X = this.X, Y = this.Y)
    interface System.ICloneable with
        member this.Clone() = box (this.Clone())
```

then you would be able to do the following:

```
let foo1 = new Foo(X = 1, Y = 2)
let foo2 = foo1.Clone(X = 3)
```

But most likely your class only has the `ICloneable` implementation. In this case the above trick will not work out of the box, because `ICloneable.Clone` returns `obj` which doesn't have a settable `X` property. Fortunately, you can add the required method as an extension:

```
/// Original class
type Foo() =
    member val X = 0 with get, set
    member val Y = 0 with get, set
    interface System.ICloneable with
        member this.Clone() = box (new Foo(X = this.X, Y = this.Y))

let foo1 = new Foo(X = 1, Y = 2)
let foo2 = foo1.Clone(X = 3) // error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Clone' is not defined
let foo3 = (foo1 :> System.ICloneable).Clone(X = 3) // error FS0495: The member or object constructor 'Clone' has no argument or settable return property 'X'. The required signature is System.ICloneable.Clone() : obj.

/// Extension that makes the above trick work
type Foo with
    member this.Clone() = (this :> System.ICloneable).Clone() :?> Foo

let foo1 = new Foo(X = 1, Y = 2)
let foo2 = foo1.Clone(X = 3) // works!
```